# How to handle Shiro Authorization Exception?

Tags: spring, web-applications, zk, shiro

i've started using shiro 1.1.0 in a web application using spring mvc 3.0.5 and zk 5.0.8 as admin. i  wasn't having shiro annotation working so i specified the requredroles  in the security application context :

```
/admin = authc, roles[ADMIN]
```

which works fine and redirect me to the unautorized paged i created.
Now i got the Annotation working so i used @RequiresRoles(value={"manager","admin","superadmin"}) on top of a class:

```
@RequiresRoles(value = {"manager","admin","superadmin"})
public class ContentController extends GenericForwardComposer {...}
```

and it throws

> org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException: Subject does not have role [manager]

Is there anything to activate when using annotation for these kind of authorization to be caught?

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

According to RequireRoles [javadoc](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/annotation/RequiresRoles.html) it should be defined on a method not on a class. If the current Subject doesn't have required role then Shiro should redirect to access denied page.

[**UPDATE**] I see there is an open issue on Shiro issue tracker for the same [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-343). So it should be applicable at class level as well. [Here](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/RequiresRoles-interception-on-class-td7193081.html) is the relevant thread.